# If we have the Bezout coefficient, how to find the smallest possible coefficient that can take its place?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

The question is the following:

"Determine the pair of numbers m,n such that gcd(1234,5678)=1234⋅m+5678⋅n for which n is the smallest positive integer".

I found that m=704 and n=-153. But n is negative here, so that can't be an answer. I assumed I could take 154 (since it's a multiple of 2) and add it to -153, which would give 1 and 1 is in ℤ2. However the pair (m,n)=(1,704) doesn't make much sense to me.

Why was my solution wrong and what is the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Hint:  to continue your solution, add $\dfrac{1234}2 $ to $-153$, and subtract $\dfrac{5678}2$ from $704$.  Do you see why that works?

Comment: $2 = 1234 m+ 5678 m \iff 1 = \color{#c00}{617}m + 2839 n \iff n \equiv 2839^{-1} \pmod{\color{#c00}{617}}.\,$ You computed  $\,n = -153,\,$ whose least positive residue $\bmod \color{#c00}{617}\,$ is  $\,617-153 = 464\ \ $